# "File being used by another process" error after modifying app.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config

I am writing a simple reporting application that pulls data from a SQL database on an external server, and sends out HTML email messages based on said data.

The project builds and executes perfectly 99% of the time, with the exception being after I modify the app.config file. The very first build and run (in Visual Studio 2012 Pro) after modifying the app.config file yields the following error:

"The operation could not be completed. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

The build succeeds, but this error is generated immediately following build.

I have found several other users with a similar problem, and the solutions were varied. None had the same error for the same reason. A number of people attributed the error to a VS debugger issue.

Has anyone else experienced the same issue, or does anyone know what may cause this? Note that I get the same error in both Debug and Release. The same error is generated even if the connection string is not encrypted.

I have included the app.config file below, as well as all code that accesses config information.

Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="minimum_days" value="40"/>
    <add key="maximum_days" value="70"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>          
              <CipherValue>......ciphertext...</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
          <CipherValue>...ciphertext...</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Access Code:

```
private int min_threshold = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("minimum_days"));
private int max_threshold = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("maximum_days"));
private string connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["str1"].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: This happened to me all the time in the past and for example everytime when I pressed Stop during debugging the build engine locked some of my files. I'm afraid you'd either need to use a newer VS or use the ReSharper build engine. It never happened to me again since I switched it.